# How-to use Play 2.4.x with scalaz 7.2.0

Tags: playframework, scalaz, specs2

It seems that there is some issue due to the version of specs2.

Here are the errors when I compile the test :

```
[error] Uncaught exception when running ServiceSpec: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class scalaz.Memo, but interface was expected
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last test:test for the full output.
[error] Uncaught exception when running ApplicationSpec: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.specs2.main.Arguments$
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last test:test for the full output.
[error] Uncaught exception when running IntegrationSpec: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.specs2.main.Arguments$
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last test:test for the full output.
[error] Uncaught exception when running FileImportSpec: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.specs2.main.Arguments$
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last test:test for the full output.
```

Is there a workaround ?

Comment: Did you check your scalaz version and make sure it is 7.2.0?. You might have another version. Load your target/resolution-cache/reports/<PROJECT>_2.11-test.xml into a browser. You may find you do not have 7.2.0 installed because of a conflict. I had a similar problem in the past and while not always easy to resolve, it at least identifies your problem.

Comment: you're right. 7.1 in test. Any idea to fix ?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; Could not find a workaroud, so I downgraded it

The problem is not Play but specs2. My version of specs2 uses : `scalaz-core` version `7.1.1`. You can find your own using the [sbt dependency graph plugin](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) (The plugin seems to hide test scoped dependencies: remove the `test` scope from specs2 dependency)

I had to downgrade the scalaz-core version to 7.1.1

```
  "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.1.1"
```

Cheers

Comment: prefix it with test  ==> test:dependcyGraph. So it will display for the test scope

Answer (score 0):

Yann, have a look at [sbt Dependency overrides](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#Overriding+a+version) to try and force the version of scalaz.

ie. I believe you need something like this in build.sbt (not tested)

```
dependencyOverrides += "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.2.0"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't fix !

Answer (score 0):

I just have had the same problem, but for Play 2.5.x. Bumbing up version both of scalaz and specs2 resolved the issue for me:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.2.7",
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "3.8.6" % "test"
)
```

Maybe one will find that helpful;)